# Predicate logic: Equivalence between two formulas

Tags: predicate-logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

Consider the following sentence:

(1) The last man on earth is the last man in the Universe.

I think that both (A) and (B) capture the form of (1) (I'm assuming Russell's theory of definite descriptions):

(A) ∃x(P(x)∧Q(x)∧∀y((P(y)∨Q(y))⊃x=y))

(B) ∃x∃y(P(x)∧∀z(P(z)→z=x)∧Q(y)∧∀z(Q(z)→z=y)∧x=y)

P = last man on earth   Q = last man in the Universe

But I was asking myself if (A) and (B) really are logically equivalent. In particular, I'm worried about (A) being compatible with the existence of several last men on earth, or with several last men in the Universe. Are (A) and (B) logically equivalent? If not, why?

Comment: Can you translate these formulas to more plain English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they really are equivalent. With the identity in there the algebra to demonstrate equivalence is a bit hairy, and a formal proof also takes about 40-50 lines, but they really are equivalent.

And at the very least it is easy to demonstrate that a) does not allow for more than one last man on Earth or more than one last man in the Universe, because the $\forall y ((P(y) \lor Q(y)) \rightarrow x=y)$ part in a) will guarantee that anyone who is either the last man on Earth or the last man in the Universe will have to be identical to $x$.  In fact, here is an equivalence that is easy to demonstrate that may help in seeing that:

$\forall y ((P(y) \lor Q(y)) \rightarrow x=y) \Leftrightarrow $ (Implication)

$\forall y (\neg (P(y) \lor Q(y)) \lor x=y) \Leftrightarrow$ (DeMorgan)

$\forall y((\neg P(y) \land \neg Q(y)) \lor x =y) \Leftrightarrow$ (Distribution)

$\forall y ((\neg P(y) \lor x=y) \land (\neg Q(y) \lor x=y)) \Leftrightarrow$ (Implication x2)

$\forall y (P(y) \rightarrow x=y) \land (Q(y) \rightarrow x=y))$ (Distribution $\forall$ over $\land$)

$\forall y (P(y) \rightarrow x=y) \land \forall y (Q(y) \rightarrow x=y)$

ADDENDUM

You asked for a tree  .... here is a tree:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I suppose that in order to demonstrate that (A) and (B) are equivalent I should build refutation trees and show that (A) entails (B) and (B) entails (A). Does someone know about a reliable tree proof generator (which includes identity) that I could download or - even better - use online? This would simpler than building the trees myself, and less prone to errors.

Comment: In fact, I really need to provide a proof that (A) and (B) are equivalent.

Comment: @Fishermansfriend Do you have to do a tree, or can you use a formal proof?

Comment: @Fishermansfriend I added a tree ...

Comment: Thank you so much! How did you build this tree? Which tool did you use?

Comment: @Fishermansfriend It's called MS Word :).  I saw your other post asking about an online or downloadable tool for doing those, but that German website you listed is the best one I know as well, and like you said, it doesn't have identity. So, I had to create this tree by hand.

Comment: In fact I found this one http://creativeandcritical.net/prooftools and it seems to work pretty well!

Comment: @Fishermansfriend Hey, thanks!  That looks promising. I'll check it out!